# How can I read and filter many parquet files with different column names without spending many hours

Tags: python, for-loop, pyspark, parquet

I have a lot of files on parquet, i need jut jo take 3 columns of this files. Some times one of this columns can have different names. I have this code but, this is spending more than 3 hours to run. This is not good. i'm using pyspark.

```
df_list = []
# I iterate all paths from a df which contains all file paths that i need

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    path = adl_gen2_full_url(DATALAKE,FILESYSTEM,'/APPLICATION/'+row['Ingested_Path'])
    
    
    
    try:
        
        spark_df = spark.read.parquet(path)
        # Here i select just the columns that i need, one of this columns have different name
        spark_df = spark_df.select(row['Data_referencia'] \
                                  ,'data_upload' \
                                  ,'data_processamento' \
                                  )

        
        spark_df = spark_df.withColumn("nome_arquivo",F.lit(row['Nome_Arquivo']))
        spark_df = spark_df.distinct()
    
      
        # Each file that i read i append on a list                               
        df_list.append(spark_df)
        
        print("\n")
        print("Sucesso ", row['Nome_Arquivo'])
        print("\n")
        
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print("Connection refused")
        print(path)
        pass
        
    
    except Exception as e:
        print("Internal error", e)
        pass

        
# In the end, i reduce that list in a unique dataframe       
dfs = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, df_list)


dfs = dfs.filter(F.col('data_referência') != 'NaT')
```

Comment: Have you measured what the slow part is using e.g. a profiler? For instance, is your code possibly loading the entire parquet file just to filter it locally?

Comment: @AKX on pyspark i can't do that step by step cause the way pyspark is executed.

Answer (score 1):

**1**) You are trying to filter the final combined set of dataframes by `data_referência`. If that field (with value `NaT`) has some share in most (or all) collected dataframes - your code will accumulate a lot of redundant data appended to `df_list` with further passing to `union`. So it makes sense to filter out those records from each dataframe: 
`spark_df = spark_df.filter(F.col('data_referência') != 'NaT')` (instead of filtering at the end).

**2**) Note that `DataFrame.unionAll` is just an alias (some say it's deprecated) for `DataFrame.union`. According to your comment `# ... reduce that list in a unique dataframe` - union doesn't make a unique dataframe, it just combines a dataframes. Potentially, you could have a duplicate rows **between** combined dataframes, so perhaps `reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, df_list).distinct()`. 
Another related aspect is executing `spark_df.distinct()` on each dataframe: if you can monitor/debug that the **difference** in size of one such filtered dataframe before `distinct()` and after it is in average very negligible - then try to omit distincting every df and call `dictinct` once on the final combined dataset as mentioned above.

Comment: Good points! 
I learned with you My execution time is better now.